# How to call a function wrapped in a TaskKey?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a `TaskKey[String => String]` and would like to apply the function on a provided string. I am trying the following, with string "foo":

```scala
val x = Project.extract(state)
import x._
val task: TaskKey[String => String] = ...
val taskFunc = task in currentRef get structure.data // Option[Task[String => String]]
val taskValue = taskFunc.map(_.value.apply("foo")).getOrElse("foo") // String
```

I get an error because of the call to `_.value`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it except inside another task.

```scala
someOtherTaskKey := {
  functionTaskKey.value.apply("foo")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the following to work:

```scala
val x = Project.extract(state)
import x._
val task: TaskKey[String => String] = ...
val taskFunc = x.runTask(task, state)._2 // String => String
val taskValue = taskFunc("foo") // String
```